# Creating a new DataFrame getting only Columns with a variable = True

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

Still new in Python.
I have found that the Y-axis always is scaled to the whole DataFrame using plt.show() when plotting a part of the x-axis (Date)
I have made a variable 'plot' in the complete DataFrame with values False/True depending on the Date range I want to plot.
How do I make a new DataFrame plotdata with all data where 'plot' has value "True" in order to rescale the Y-axis.

```
data['plot'] = (data['Date'] > startplot) & (data['Date'] <= end) 
print(data)
plotdata = pd.DataFrame()

plotdata = pd.DataFrame([data('plot') == 'True'])
```

.
.

My print(data) looks like this:

```
     Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume   plot
0   2015-01-02  47.00  47.23  46.91  46.96  11421233  False

1   2015-01-05  47.08  47.16  46.56  46.57  18964458  False

2   2015-01-06  46.79  47.38  46.46  47.04  22950060  False

3   2015-01-07  46.92  47.04  46.05  46.19  20793637  False

.
.

644 2017-07-25  43.90  44.17  43.81  43.98   9818802   True

645 2017-07-26  44.80  44.83  44.28  44.40  19045166   True

646 2017-07-27  46.26  47.84  45.95  47.81  44702494   True

647 2017-07-28  47.70  48.38  47.12  47.94  25296508   True
```

I have searched and looked a lot without success. Hope someone has a solution. Thanks / Henning

Comment: `plotdata=data[data['plot']]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
plotdata=data[data['plot']]
plotdata
Out[470]: 
           Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  plot
644  2017-07-25  43.90  44.17  43.81  43.98   9818802  True
645  2017-07-26  44.80  44.83  44.28  44.40  19045166  True
646  2017-07-27  46.26  47.84  45.95  47.81  44702494  True
647  2017-07-28  47.70  48.38  47.12  47.94  25296508  True
```

Comment: Cool. Exactly. Thanks. / Henning